# Can get multiple output in console.log, but not HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to output multiple values from Firebase on to my HTML document however, I can get all child outputs using console.log but when I try to add it into HTML it only outputs 1 value. I tried to use forEach, but I can't get it to work (Not sure if I've made an error).

The code I have so far is

```
const dbRefObjectPosts = dbRefObject.child('Posts');

    dbRefObjectPosts.on("value", function(snap){
        snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            document.getElementById('object').innerHTML = (
                "Title: " + childSnapshot.val().Title + "</br>" +
                "Message: " + childSnapshot.val().Message + "</br>" +
                "Posted: " + childSnapshot.val().Posted
            );
            console.log(childSnapshot.val().Message);
        });
    });
```

The html output is

```
Title: 6756775
Message: 56756575776
Posted: Date: 19/3/2017 @ 23:2:40
```

the console.log output is

```
out with friends
BLOG.js:61 this is a test
BLOG.js:61 03:11 am and this is kind of working.
BLOG.js:61 The time is now 03:59 and things are coming good finally.
BLOG.js:61 Ok time is 04:42 going to my bed.
BLOG.js:61 5676576756575
BLOG.js:61 56756575776
```

Comment: Try `.innerHTML += ...` When you do `.innerHTML = `, you replace previous value by new value.

Comment: @Rajesh thanks that worked for most of it, but the title is only outputting once any ideas how to get around that ?

Comment: Just a pointer, create `htmlString` in loop and set it once after loop. Manipulating DOM in loop is a bad practice. Also try logging the final string. That might help you in figuring issue with title. Its difficult to visualise it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script will resolve your issue.

```
    dbRefObjectPosts.on("value", function(snap){
        snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            document.getElementById('object').innerHTML += (
                "Title: " + childSnapshot.val().Title + "</br>" +
                "Message: " + childSnapshot.val().Message + "</br>" +
                "Posted: " + childSnapshot.val().Posted +
                "<br/><br/>"
            );
            console.log(childSnapshot.val().Message);
        });
    });
```